# UIDatePicker showing the wrong time swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

```
func show(title: String, doneButtonTitle: String = "Done", cancelButtonTitle: String = "Cancel", defaultDate: NSDate = NSDate(), datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode = .DateAndTime, callback: DatePickerCallback) {
    self.titleLabel.text = title
    self.doneButton.setTitle(doneButtonTitle, forState: .Normal)
    self.cancelButton.setTitle(cancelButtonTitle, forState: .Normal)
    self.datePickerMode = datePickerMode
    self.callback = callback
    self.defaultDate = defaultDate
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = self.datePickerMode ?? .Date
    self.datePicker.date = self.defaultDate ?? NSDate()
    self.datePicker.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    /* */
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first!.addSubview(self)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first!.endEditing(true)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    /* Anim */
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.2,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
            self.dialogView!.layer.opacity = 1
            self.dialogView!.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
        },
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

Hi , when i call `self.datePicker.date` return 3 hours back. How can i fix this problem i added `self.datePicker.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()` but the problem not fixed. I can add more information if needed.

Comment: have you done something like that extension NSDate {
    var localTime: String {
       return descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())! 
    }
}

println(chosenDate.localTime)

Comment: Yes this code part fixed problem can you send this code with answer i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date picker uses its local time but it stores UTC time. It means your local time offset is -5h. You can do as follow to extract the right date and time from it:

```
extension NSDate {
    var localTime: String {
       return descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())! 
    }
}

println(chosenDate.localTime)
```

Props to [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus)`